# Datasheet and information needed about 6C17504 and 1D17409 8-pin ICs

Tags: identification, datasheet

I have a power supply of an [Epson EB-X41 projector](https://www.epson.co.uk/products/projectors/mobile/eb-x41) that doesn't turn on. I haven't found the problem yet, but in the power supply circuit it has 2 ICs for which I couldn't find any datasheet or information. I think they should be switching ICs, but it's so strange for me why there is no data about them.

What are these ICs? do they have datasheets available?

[image: photo of unknown IC]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The logo is reminiscent of Cypress semiconductor. Usually when projectors refuses to turn on its because of lamp slot interlock or the ballast does not give power ok. Check those first.

Comment: ok, thanks, but i think in those cases the leds power on with green or red or ... colors and power  off again, but my projector doesn't react at all

Comment: Which supply rails does come up and which doesn’t?

Answer (score 1):

As the [allaboutcircuits](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/datasheet-and-information-about-6c17504-and-1d17409-8pin-ic.176624/) reply said, the first could be [8A01 rectifiers](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/1418918/YiTaiElectron/8A01/1), but IC version.

The one remaining could be an [FA5612 power supply control IC](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/422941/FUJI/FA5612.html).

---

I searched `5612 ic datasheet`.

Comment: are u serious? 8a01 is an axial 2 pin device and my parts are 8 pin ic

Comment: 8A01 **IC** - could be four in the IC. Just look up 8A01 in an eight pin package.

Comment: i didn't see 8-pin package in sent datasheet

Comment: Changed answer to, "could be 8A01 rectifiers, but IC version."